# ProgressDialog crash in fragment after first run

Tags: android, android-fragments, progressdialog

First of all I have to say that I've read some few posts about this issue but no one solves my problem.

On the first run of the app, an intro activity is launched to request some data:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ...

        //If first run, an intro is shown
        if (!isIntroShown()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntroWellcomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            setIntroShown(true);
            finish();
        }

        //Navigation drawer set up
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(this);

        setUpToolbar();
        setUpNavDrawer();

        displayFragment(R.id.navigation_item_1);

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                displayFragment(menuItem.getItemId());
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

When it returns after the intro, the Navigation Drawer is shown for first time as the documentation states and the default fragment is loaded.

This fragment shows the info introduced in the intro, for example, a phone number. In this fragment, I can change this number if I want. If I do this, I show a Progress Dialog while the background job is done.

But here comes the problem. On this first run, I don't understand well why this is happening, but when the Progress dialog should be shown, the app crashes showing this on the logCat.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp, PID: 31388
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@55b185f is not valid; is your activity running?
```

After this, I run again the app. This time the intro is not showing, neither the navigation drawer (this only happens on the first run), and if I try again to edit the phone number, the Progress Dialog is shown and everything works fine.

This is how I initiate the ProgressDialog in the fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    ...
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
```

I've tryed using getActivity() instead of getContext() but doesn't solve the problem.

So I guess that on the first run after the intro is shown, and the fragment is loaded, something is not being initiated, or I'm initiating the progressDialog in the wrong place. I don't know.

Comment: Use getActivity() to initialize ProgressDialog and try if(!getActivity().isFinishing()){progressDialog.show()) while showing the progress dialog. And also check whether the progressDialog is already showing. If Yes dismiss and reinitialize it.

Comment: can you try passing this in ProgressDialog constructor : getActivity().getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you create a fragment inside an activity on which you call `finish()` before you show the dialog. Try to not call `finish()` in your  `if (!isIntroShown())` statement.

From the intro/tutorial you can return to the same created activity later without killing it in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! this is what has worked! I new that it should be something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur when you are showing the dialog for a context that no longer exist so when to try to initialize your `ProgressDialog` check whether Activity is running.

```
if(!((Activity) getActivity()).isFinishing()){
     progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
}
```

Comment: I've seen this on other posts but is not what I need. The ProgressDialog must be started anyway.

Comment: How can you start your progress dialog when there is no active `Context`?